# how to use transaction in sequelize using nodejs

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

**Below code throw** "TypeError: sequelize.transaction is not a function" **Error**

```
sequelize.transaction(transaction => {
          myDb.myTable.findAll({attributes:['IMAGEPATH'],where:{ID : customerId}})
          .then((result) => {

          ....

          }).then((commitResult) =>{
                //commit
          }).catch((rollbackErr) =>{
                //rollback  

          })
```

Comment: How are you importing `sequelize`?

Comment: var sequelize = require("sequelize");

in my route.

Answer (score 10):

It looks like you're trying to reference the `transaction` function on the definition as opposed to the instance i.e.

```
const sequelize = require('sequelize');
sequelize.transaction(...); // doesn't exist
```

You need to create a sequelize instance and use the `transaction` function on this

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = new Sequelize(...);
db.transaction(...); // works
```

See the [docs](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/transactions.html).